# How to Output() events from components in ng2 submodules?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I have two components with very simple output event and handler, trying to pass a value from a child submodule to a component in my `app.module`. Here is my **app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <sidebar *ngIf="showHeader" (everySecond)="everySecond()" ></sidebar>
  <navbar *ngIf="showHeader" (toggleNav)="toggleNav($event)"></navbar>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
  directives: [homeComponent, sidebarComponent, navbarComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
  everySecond() { console.log('second'); }
}
```

In my **app.module.ts** I import `tutorialModule` which includes the following component.

```
export class tutorialComponent {
  @Output() everySecond = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {
    this.everySecond.emit("event");
    console.log("here");
  }
}
```

However, when I route to the `tutorialComponent`, the "here2 log is printed out, but the "second" one is never triggered. I assume this is because the tutorialComponent isn't declared as a directive of the app.component (as it is imported as a module). How do I get this to work?

Comment: Did you try to place "this.everySecond.emit("event")" in ngOnInit method?

Answer (score 1):

You need to subscribe to `everySecond` in your app component:

for example:

```
this.tutorialComponent.everySecond.subscribe((data) => {
   console.log('second');
});
```

Comment: Where does `this.tutorialComponent` come from? There is currently no ref to it in my component, only in the module import.

Answer (score 0):

If you emit the event in the constructor, no data binding is set up yet and the event won't be noticed by a potential receiver.
If you move the code to `ngOnInit()` then the event is emitted **after** the component is initialized and data binding is set up.

```
export class tutorialComponent {
  @Output() everySecond = new EventEmitter();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.everySecond.emit("event");
    console.log("here");
  }
}
```

Comment: I am afraid that even with that, I get "here" printed to the console, but no "second" ...

Comment: Seems to work in this simplified Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/TIwTT8NudaFKrqkZweax?p=preview

Comment: I thins the issue (not replicated in your plunk) is linked to using the subModule rather than another child component

Comment: EventEmitter only works with direct children and only with stativslly added components and directives. Components added by the router can't emit events thid way. Here you need a shared service and observables.